# How include the root view in the shell

Tags: sapui5

I see this example 
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.ui.unified.Shell/samples

Now I have a root view (this.app) and all works fine.

```
return this.app;
```

Now I want include the root app in a shell container..
I try to do this:

```
var oShell= new sap.m.Shell("idShell", {
            title: "Test App",
            logo:"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7546923/OpenUI5/SAPUI5.png",
            headerRightText: "This is a sap.m.Shell",
            logout: function() {alert("Logout button was pressed");}
        });

oShell.setApp(this.app);

return oShell;
```

But in this way I can't see the bar on the top. (I see only the app limited in width and the logo out of the app, on left)

I try to do this:

```
var oShell= new sap.m.Shell("idShell", {
            title: "Test App",
            logo:"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7546923/OpenUI5/SAPUI5.png",
            headerRightText: "This is a sap.m.Shell",
            logout: function() {alert("Logout button was pressed");}
        });

oShell.setApp(sap.ui.xmlview("view.shell"));  //the view of the example in the documentation

return oShell;
```

### In this way I can see the bar but I can't associate the root app in the content of shell

Now I use sap.ui.unified.Shell

```
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.unified.Shell");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.unified.ShellHeadItem");
this.shell = new sap.ui.unified.Shell('');

var logout=new sap.ui.unified.ShellHeadItem({
    tooltip: "Logout",
    icon: "sap-icon://menu2"
});

this.shell.addHeadItem(logout);


this.shell.addContent(this.app);
```

How can I use a MVC pattern to manage the shell bar content? I want use an XML-view. And how can I avoid to write

```
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.unified.Shell");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.unified.ShellHeadItem");
```

?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
new sap.m.Shell("Shell", {
  app: sap.ui.jsview("RootView", "my-app.view.App")
}).placeAt("root");
```

While the root control of `my-app.view.App` is a `sap.m.SplitApp` (or `sap.m.App`). Note that the `sap.m.Shell` is just providing a frame it is NOT providing any NavContainer, Page or similar concept you usually use in sap.m. What is the root control in your `view.shell`? From the docs:

> getApp() : sap.ui.core.Control
>
> Getter for aggregation app. A Shell contains an App or a SplitApp
>   (they may be wrapped in a View). Other control types are not allowed.

Btw: Your example link is not working for me.

BR
Chris

Comment: My root app (this.app) is a SplitApp.
@cschuff I change the link

Comment: The link is concerning sap.ui.unified.Shell, your code shows a sap.m.Shell. What are you using?

Comment: I write:
`this.shell = new sap.m.Shell("Shell", {
           app: this.app
         });`

where `this.app` is my SplitApp

This is the result. 

http://i58.tinypic.com/2uz3wqr.png

How can I view the element on a bar? (Logout, search, user..)

Comment: If I add `this.shell.setShowLogout(true).setHeaderRightText('test test test').setShowLogout(true).setTitle('title title title');` I have the same result

Comment: It appears that the Shell header is hidden by default in sap_bluecrystal theme. Only the logo will be visible on big screens (left to the content). Search for the class .sapMShellHeader. In there you find title and logout but it's hidden. You will have to style it yourself: http://de.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2v8ri44&s=8#.VEZNrBAjPj4

Comment: I update my question: I use sap.ui.unified.Shell but I want use XML view to manage the bar of shell

Comment: You can put whatever control in the search property that will end up in the bar. This could also be a xmlview. Please familiarize yourself with the API docs they would have answered half of your questions. Upvotes are appreciated btw.